# TimeEntry() cause httpget request to controller in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I did searching, some similiar problem may be different, for mine I have route setting

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{year}/{num}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Supervisory", action = "Page1", year = UrlParameter.Optional, num = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

in controller Page1(int year, string num) [httpget]

in view I have  time entry from jquery.timeentry.js

```
$(function () {
     $('.TimeField').timeEntry();
});
```

if I request http://{server}/supervisory/page1/2014/0001, the Page1 action in controller is called twice, one request from timeEntry() if I remove it, it is ok, or if I don't have parameter year and num, it works fine too. any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by "request from timeEntry()"? How could js function called your backend without any information?

Comment: you are right, I have no idea, why js function cause a request to backend, but the reality is like that, if I remove this js func, no second request.

Comment: And if you call http://{server} it works as well?

Comment: yes, it works, just one request

Comment: Well...try to debug what's happening inside of timeEntry(). I can only imagine that it refresh the window (I really don't know, why).

Comment: jquery.timeentry.js is third party js, even I trace into it,  verything works fine, after get back a request generate, the interface is like this                             /* Initialise the time entry functionality. */
var plugin = $.timeEntry = new TimeEntry(); // Singleton instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to those who may meet same issue, in jquery.timeentry.js, there is spinnerimage which call backend.

```
var spinner = (!inst.options.spinnerImage ? null :
        $('<span class="' + this._controlClass + '" style="display: inline-block; ' +
        'background: url(\'' + inst.options.spinnerImage + '\') 0 0 no-repeat; width: ' +
        inst.options.spinnerSize[0] + 'px; height: ' + inst.options.spinnerSize[1] + 'px;"></span>'));
```

You can change it by your requestments.